# Chef can't see all attributes

Tags: chef-infra

I'm running Chef11 and in the details of one of my nodes I have a particular attribute. However, if I go to Edit, the attribute is not in the json view. If I manually add the attribute to the json and save it, then it works as expected. I have this issue with several attributes and would definitely prefer not to have to manually edit. Any ideas?

Edit: Added some screen shots

[image: You can see the <code>port</code> attribute here]

But when editing, it is not available in the `json` section

[image: No <code>port</code> attribute under <code>mongodb</code>]

Comment: We can't help without the code snippets or steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That view in Manage (btw a product that has been superseded by Automate) only shows attributes set directly on the node. If the attribute is coming from a role, environment, or cookbook, you would have to edit that rather than the node.

Comment: Ok I'll double check that.

Comment: So I have confirmed that this is indeed the case.